# How to add event on mouse scroll and right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to create a minesweeper game, where a right click would add a flag. The right click event, however, is currently not working, i.e, not able get the value of `event.which` for right and middle mouse button. Just getting  `contextMenu`.

Sample JS:

```
var trig = function (event) {
  if(event.which==1){
    //do something on left click
  }
  else if(event.which === 3)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.isDefaultPrevented());
    //Do something on right click.
  }
}

$('.block').click(trig);
```

Can anyone please tell, a plausible reason why that is happening?

*preventDefault was only added as the conextmenu was becoming annoying.*

Comment: I did a full implementation of minesweeper in Vue.js a year ago: https://github.com/franktopel/vue-defuse

Comment: Playable online here: https://connexo.de/defuse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button)

**0** for Left mouse button, **1** for Wheel button or middle button (if present) and
**2** for Right mouse button.

Internet Explorer 8 and earlier has different values:

**1** for Left mouse button, **2** for Right mouse button and
**4** for Wheel button or middle button (if present).

Change

```
else if(event.which === 3)
```

To

```
else if(event.which === 2 || event.which === 3)
```

**OR:** For IE <= 8

```
else if(event.which === 2 || event.which === 4)
```

Comment: @Dark_thunder, which browser you are using? You can try removing ` event.preventDefault();`........

Comment: currently on chrome Version 69.0.3497.100
but have tried it in edge as well.
also I removed `event.preventDefault' , still not working

Comment: [`MouseEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which) is non-standard. Prefer [`MouseEvent.button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button), unless you're using jQuery, which normalizes [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: @jeto i'm actually using jQuery, but I wil give it a try on MouseEvent.button

Comment: wait my bad , I used click rather than mouseDown, by the wat thanks it works now.